# Python - неправильное поведение программы при подготовке вывода

Tags: python, вывод

Переменная `toOutput` не заполняется, в чем может быть проблема?

Программа еще не закончена, но эта часть кода не работает так, как ожидалось:

```
eng="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

rus="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"

print("Выберите язык (eng/rus)>>> ")

language=""

def lang(x):
    x=str(input())
    if x!="eng" and x!="rus":
        lang(x)

lang(language)

print("Расшифровать или зашифровать текст? (dec/enc) >>>")

DecCod=""

def forcode(t):
    t=str(input())
    if t!="dec" and t!="enc":
        lang(t)

forcode(DecCod)

text=str(input("Введите текст>>> "))
keyTo=str(input("Введите ключ>>> "))

toOutput=""

def makeText():
    global text,language,keyTo,DecCod,toOutput,eng,rus
    if DecCod=="enc":
        if language=="eng":
            k=0
            for l in text:
                if k+1>len(keyTo):
                    k=0
                else:
                    firstDigit=int(eng.find(str(l)))
                    secondDigit=int(eng.find(keyTo[k]))
                    toOutput+=eng[firstDigit+secondDigit-len(eng)+1]
                    k+=1
        elif language=="rus":
            k=0
            for l in text:
                if k+1>len(keyTo):
                    k=0
                else:
                    firstDigit=int(rus.find(l))
                    secondDigit=int(rus.find(keyTo[k]))
                    toOutput+=rus[firstDigit+secondDigit-len(rus)+1]
                    k+=1

makeText()
print(toOutput)
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в Питоне строки передаются в функцию по значению, а не по ссылке. Соответственно, переменные переданные в методы `lang` и `forcode` имеют локальную область видимости и их изменения не отражаются на глобальных переменных. Чтобы это исправить, нужно возвращать полученную внутри функции строку командой `return`.

Не очень понятно, зачем вы используете в тех методах рекурсию, когда достаточно простого цикла.

В методе `makeText` также лучше передавать значения строк в аргументах, а созданную строку возвращать из функции.

Ещё незачем писать `str(input())`. Ведь метод `input()` уже возвращает строку.

Вот, что получилось:

```
eng="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

rus="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"

print("Выберите язык (eng/rus)>>> ")

def lang():
    x = input()
    while x!="eng" and x!="rus":
        x = input()
    return x

language = lang()

print("Расшифровать или зашифровать текст? (dec/enc) >>>")


def forcode():
    t = input()
    while t!="dec" and t!="enc":
        t = input()
    return t

DecCode = forcode()

text = input("Введите текст>>> ")
keyTo = input("Введите ключ>>> ")

def makeText(text, language, keyTo, DecCode, eng, rus):
    #global text,language,keyTo,DecCod,toOutput,eng,rus
    toOutput = ""
    if DecCode=="enc":
        if language=="eng":
            k=0
            for l in text:
                if k+1>len(keyTo):
                    k=0
                else:
                    firstDigit=int(eng.find(str(l)))
                    secondDigit=int(eng.find(keyTo[k]))
                    toOutput+=eng[firstDigit+secondDigit-len(eng)+1]
                    k+=1
        elif language=="rus":
            k=0
            for l in text:
                if k+1>len(keyTo):
                    k=0
                else:
                    firstDigit=int(rus.find(l))
                    secondDigit=int(rus.find(keyTo[k]))
                    toOutput+=rus[firstDigit+secondDigit-len(rus)+1]
                    k+=1
    return toOutput

toOutput = makeText(text, language, keyTo, DecCode, eng, rus)
print(toOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что при вызове `makeText()` переменные `DecCod == language ==""`. Вы присвоили им начальное значение, но не прочитали. Точнее прочитали, поигрались в функциях, но не сохранили в ваши переменные.